# 205 nm UV-Vis readings

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, lab-techniques

Typically we determine the concentration of proteins using a 280 nm reading. However, it is reasonable to use 205 nm. I was curious about the effectiveness of this method.

Comment: What evidence do you have for the reasonableness of reading at 205?

Comment: @MattDMo: I guess it is because usually nucleic acids are measured at 260. However, I am not sure 205 would remove DNA background noise... These are very approximative quantifications anyways, and only give a general idea of protein concentration.

Comment: @MattDMo, I didn't want to lead the question but I was looking over this paper. There is a scientific basis for the quetion. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/pro.2253/abstract

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~bioslabs/methods/protein/abs205.html) may be what you are looking for. The conversion formula is:

$$
\text{Protein concentration (mg/ml)} = \frac{ (\text{Absorbance at 205 nm})} {31}
$$

The first, [Scopes](http://xa.yimg.com/kq/groups/14971503/107426481/name/9.pdf), does indicate that nucleic acid contaminants will confounding 205 nm absorbance readings. It seems as though this spetrophotometic calculation is feasible for relatively pure protein species.

Comment: DNA absorbance seems to be as high at 205 as at 260. http://faculty.evansville.edu/be6/b4454/DNAspectrum.gif?dur=2225

Comment: You would appear to be correct. What is not shown is relative absorbance of protein and nucleic acid at 205 nm. NB: I have not followed up with the two references linked from that page I posted.

Comment: I wanted to emphasize that A280nm is more sensitive, as tryptophan's absorbance is highest. So you can detect the smallest concentrations with A280nm. For proteins with little-to-no aromatics, or for proteins with atypical compositions (and unknown absorption coefficients), the absorbance per-unit-peptide bond is more general. (That's what A205nm is probing.) But as others have said, contaminating nucleic acids will also absorb at that wavelength.